# How to select certain ID from MySql database with php

Tags: php, mysql

How can i echo a certain id from a row in MySql with php?

I have this piece of code which shows me all the values from a DB:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
// some code goes here 
$HTML.='
    <li>
        <h4 class="">'.$row['product_name'].'</h4>

        <div class="grid">
            '.$like.'
        </div>
    </li>';
```

And finally somewhere in the page:

```
<ul class="thumbnail-list">
    <?php echo $HTML; ?>
</ul>
```

This shows me all the product_names (Photos) but i want to seperate them all from each other. My DB looks like this:
[image]

How can i echo al the `Photos` seperately from each other?

UPDATE:

My While loops looks like this:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
// get likes and dislikes of a product
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"select sum(`like`) as `like`,sum(`unlike`) as `unlike` from `likes` where pid = ".$row['id']);
$rowCount = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
if($rowCount['like'] == "")
    $rowCount['like'] = 0;

if($rowCount['unlike'] == "")
    $rowCount['unlike'] = 0;

if($uid == "") // if user not loggedin then show login link on like button click
{
    $like = '
        <input onclick="location.href = \'login.php\';" type="button" value="'.$rowCount['like'].'" rel="'.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="top" title="Login to Like" class="button_like" />
        <input onclick="location.href = \'login.php\';" type="button" value="'.$rowCount['unlike'].'" rel="'.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Login to Unlike" class="button_unlike" />';
}
else
{
    $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * from `likes` WHERE pid='".$row['id']."' and uid='".$uid."'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){ //if already liked od disliked a product
        $likeORunlike = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        // clear values of variables
        $liked = '';
        $unliked = '';
        $disable_like = '';
        $disable_unlike = '';

        if($likeORunlike['like'] == 1) // if alredy liked then disable like button
        {
            $liked = 'disabled="disabled"';
            $disable_unlike = "button_disable";
        }
        elseif($likeORunlike['unlike'] == 1) // if alredy dislike the disable unlike button
        {
            $unliked = 'disabled="disabled"';
            $disable_like = "button_disable";
        }

        $like = '
        <input '.$liked.' type="button" value="'.$rowCount['like'].'" rel="'.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="top" title="Like" class="button_like '.$disable_like.'" id="linkeBtn_'.$row['id'].'" />
        <input '.$unliked.' type="button" value="'.$rowCount['unlike'].'" rel="'.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Un-Like" class="button_unlike '.$disable_unlike.'" id="unlinkeBtn_'.$row['id'].'" />
        ';
    }
    else{ //not liked and disliked product
        $like = '
        <input  type="button" value="'.$rowCount['like'].'" rel="'.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="top" title="Like" class="button_like" id="linkeBtn_'.$row['id'].'" />
        <input  type="button" value="'.$rowCount['unlike'].'" rel="'.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Un-Like" class="button_unlike" id="unlinkeBtn_'.$row['id'].'" />
        ';
    }
}

$HTML.='
    <li>
        <h4 class="">'.$row['product_name'].'</h4>

        <div class="grid">
            '.$like.'
        </div>
    </li>';
```

}

Comment: does your (unknown) query not contain a WHERE clause?

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean "seperate them all from each other."? How about you give us an example of what you'd like it to look like, based on the database you provided.

Comment: What do you mean? separately from each other? Do you want to store your results in an array and not a string? use `$HTML[]` instead?

Comment: The echo generates all the 6 Photos. But it should produce , lets say, only Photo1. I mean something like this: `<h4 class="">'.$row['product_name(with ID 1)'].'</h4>`

Comment: what is `$like` defined as? In the code snippet provided to us you do not even reference the field `image` from your query. I suggest you fill in more details. I didn't down vote you either. I'm trying to help you.

Comment: Because you're using a string, but you still have not told me what `$like` is in your question above.

Comment: Post Updated above; while loop included

Comment: Refer to my solution below, your use of a string for $HTML is what is causing you your issue. `$HTML .= ` in a loop is the same as `$HTML = $HTML + your snippet of html above`, and repeat until the loop ends. I highly recommend you use an array like in my example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to suggest you use an array over a string for your variable `$HTML`. Because your string is just concatenating all your results together which is how the code should work.

Refer to [PHP ARRAYS](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

So In your while loop do this:

```
$HTML[]='
    <li>
    <h4 class="">'.$row['product_name'].'</h4>

    <div class="grid">
        <p>Photo Name : '.$row['product_name'].' <br>
           File Name : '.$row['image'].' </p>
    </div>
</li>';
//because I know nothing about how you are retrieving your images, I am only 
//display the text value of the code as it would be in the database
```

When you echo out your `$HTML` you will need to specify which index you want in the array.

```
<ul class="thumbnail-list">
    <?php echo $HTML[0]; ?>
</ul>
<ul class="thumbnail-list">
    <?php echo $HTML[1]; ?>
</ul>
```

or alternatively if you want to loop through each element

```
foreach($HTML as $item){
    <ul class="thumbnail-list">
        <?php echo $item; ?>
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: i have updated the post with the while loop

Comment: It works perfect! Exactly what i wanted to achieve. I forgot  the `[]` in `$HTML[]='
    <li>`. But now it works as expected. thanks @mcv for this solution